# how to sort the line of a file by to the second word from the end

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, sed, cut

I want to sort the line accorfing to the last number just before the `space`. And this is a simplified example:

```
c3_abl_eerf_14 sasw
a.bla_haha_2 dnkww
s.hey_3 ddd
```

And this is the results I want:

```
a.bla_haha_2 dnkww
s.hey_3 ddd
c3_abl_eerf_14 sasw
```

I don't know how to do this, maybe by the command `sort`? And, sometimes I used the `sort` command, it may wrongly treat the 14 less than 2, I don't want this to happen.

Comment: You can not do this with `sort`, as it will only accept a single character as field separator. In order to sort numerically, use `sort -n`.

Answer (score 9):

this command chain works for your example:

```
sed -r 's/.*_([0-9]+) .*/\1 &/' file|sort -n|sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

The idea is

- extract the number first, add to the beginning of the line
- sort all lines by this number
- remove the number

#### update

sort by last number in the line, no matter where the number is:

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{$0=(length($NF)?$NF:$(NF-1)) OFS $0}7' file|sort -n|sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not very understand  how it works. Does the  `.*_([0-9]+)  .*` matches  `_[a number]`? And  `\1 &/` means copy it to the beginning? And I'm confused about the `&` , and how the last `sed` command work?

Comment: And, this is a simplified example. There may have lots of `_[numbers]`, but I just want to match the last one.  More general, there could be no `_`, the number just neighbored the char directly. And how could I do for these case? Just according to the last number of a line.

Comment: @springcc you could give a simple example, but it should represent all your requirement. So what you meant is, take the last number in each line as the key, no matter there is space/underscore or whatever?

Comment: Sure, in this case I want to take the last number as the key. And I'm also curious about how to take the second number from the end as the key.

Comment: @springcc check the **update** in answer. It take the last number to sort, no matter which column it is in.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it with GNU `awk`, try this:

```
BEGIN { FS = "[ _]+" }
{ data[$(NF-1)] = data[$(NF-1)] "\n" $0}
END {
    n = asorti(data, sorted, "@val_num_asc");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        print substr(data[sorted[i]], 2);
    }
}
```

This works as follows: The `BEGIN` rule sets the field separator (you could also do this on the command line). The second rule applies to all lines of the input and puts them into an associative array indexed by the number in the second but last field. The `END` rule sorts the indices of this array into a second array, and the following loops prints the values, now sorted.

Comment: if multiple lines have same number, e.g. change the `3` in last line into `2` what your command will print? Awk doesn't solve hashtable key collision automatically.

Comment: It will print the two lines in the correct order. The sort is stable.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I didn't test. another thing, if you used asorti, you should set "sorted_in" in order to make it sort numerically.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Thank you, however, it's beyond my understanding, could you have a brief explain? I don't understand the functions such as `BEGIN`, `END`, `asorti`, `sorted` and the `[ _]+`，`$0` and how `{ data[$(NF-1)] = data[$(NF-1)] "\n" $0}` works.